# string to object?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Consider the following code:

I receive an object from datamapper which contains Values from my select:

```
user = User.first()
puts user.name
# John
puts user.surname
# Doe
puts user.age
# 42
```

In a user defined Array I have an Order for these Values to be displayed

```
dataordering = ["age", "surname", "name"]
```

So how do I get my values ordered as in my Array?

```
dataordering.each do |sequence|
  puts user.sequence
  # this, of course, fails
end
```

I don't want to use eval(). nope.

Maybe there's even a better way to store an ordering of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick values from record this way:

```
user_attributes = user.attributes

dataordering.each do |attribute|
  puts user_attributes[attribute.to_sym]
end
```

Or use `send` method:

```
dataordering.each do |attribute|
  puts user.send attribute.to_sym
end
```

As an ordering solution, I can offer you this code:

```
dataordering.map { |attr| user.send attribute.to_sym }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the attributes method in combination with to_sym did the trick!